# JMeter Regular Expression Extractor setting variable as null

Tags: regex, jmeter

I have an http post request which replies with a number in the response body. 
[image]

I am trying to use a Regular Expression Extractor to extract this number: 
[image]

I am doing another post request using the extracted value. Unfortunately, the variable seems to be null.

[image]
[image]

Any idea of what could be wrong?

I am using JMeter 2.13.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 available solutions:

1. Use `${REGION_ID_g0}` when referring extracted value
2. Change your regular expression to add grouping as `(\d+)`

References:

- [JMeter User Manual Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html#regex) chapter
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65150-using-regex-regular-expression-extractor-with-jm) guide.